# how to keep file upload field url in single-line field

Tags: gravityforms

I have a form with two fields:

```
File upload field
Single-line field
```

I want to save the URL of the uploaded file in the single-line text field. I will also have this address for the file storage because I need that address. How should I do this?

To do this, I first created a new storage path using the gform_upload_path function, but I don't know how to insert this new path into the single-line text field. 
please help me and write the code

Comment: Can you explain why you want to save the address in a separate single-line text field? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to save the address in  a separate single-line text field so that I can use the address in another software to view the file.